# How to programatically publish content after form validation

Tags: forms, 9

I have a content type of which its `status` is set to unpublished and is disabled.
A site manager needs to publish the content after approval.

The site manager wants to skip this validation process when creating the same content and immediately publish the content after submitting the creation form.

In my `_form_validate` function:

```
  if (in_array('site_manager', $user->getRoles())) {
    if ($given_email == 'info@example.com') {
      $form_state->setValue('status', ['value' => True]);
    }
  }
```

And the value in `$form_state` is properly set to: True when inspecting with XDebug. But it does not publish the content automatically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to combine what should be two steps, into one. Validation handlers are for validation, so skipping the validation happens in the validation handler. Processing, which in this case setting is setting the node to published, happens in the submit handler.

In the validation handler:

```php
if (!in_array('site_manager', $user->getRoles()) || $given_email !== 'info@example.com') {
    // Form validation for users other than the site manager goes here.
  }
}
```

In the validation handler (assuming this is a node form):

```
if (in_array('site_manager', $user->getRoles()) && $given_email == 'info@example.com') {
    $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $node->setPublished()
      ->save();
  }
}
```

However, this is not how I would go about this. Hard coding an email address into this makes it difficult to change if the email address changes in the future. Instead, I would:

1. Create a new role.
2. Create a new permission in [MODULE].permissions.yml (don't forget to clear the registry after):

```yaml
bypass my form validation:
  title: 'Bypass my form validation'
  description: 'Bypasses validation of My Form'
  restrict access: true
```

3. Assign the new permission to the role created in step one.
4. Assign the role to the admin user who is to bypass validation.
5. Change the validation code to this:

```
if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('bypass my form validation')) {
    // Form validation for users other than the site manager goes here.
  }
}
```

6. Change the submit handler to this:

```
if (\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('bypass my form validation')) {
  $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
  $node->setPublished()
    ->save();
  }
}
```

This gives a more dynamic solution, in that the user can change their email address in the system, without having to update the code for the new email address. It also allows for adding additional users that can be skipped in the future if the need comes up, simply by assigning them the role created in step one.